# Can I ensure that AWS DynamoDB triggers are NOT handled in parallel by an AWS Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I have a scenario where I have a DynamoDB table with a trigger (a stream) to an AWS Lambda function.

I want to use DynamoDB as an Event Store and use the Lambda function to maintain a projection / aggregate view / read view of the data.

I need to make sure that when I save an `CreateEntity` event in DynamoDB and then maybe right after when I save an `UpdateEntity` that the Lambda function will process the `CreateEntity` event before the `UpdateEntity` event.

My understanding is that the parallelism of the triggers to Lambda depends on the number of Shards the DynamoDB stream consists of. So if the DynamoDB Stream that the Lambda function use have 2 shards and one event goes on Shard1 and the other event goes on Shard2 then they can be processed in parallel by two instances of the Lambda function.

So if the `CreateEntity` event is on Shard1 and `UpdateEntity` is on Shard2 then if Shard1 or the Lambda function instance for some reason is slow then the `UpdateEntity` event in Shard2 might be processed first. Meaning that it cannot be added to the projection because there is no entity created first.

Is my understanding correct?

Is there a way to ensure that the events are only processed by one instance of the Lambda function so that I can ensure the ordering of processing of the messages?

Or do I have to use something else than Lambda for this? For example DynamoDB stream to Kinesis with my own application where I can ensure that only one instance of the application is running and ensure the ordering this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is partly correct

if you CreateEntity X, and then UpdateEntity X, then in almost all of the cases.  it will happen on the same shard (entities are split on shards according their composite key).

the only case that it wont work is when your entity is split over shard, and this can happen only if you have small amount of unique entities, any many of them. and if you are in this case then you are doing something wrong..

so in your case its being ensured...

Comment: 99% of time time it works every time? So I will potentially lose 1 in 100 events since the order might be switched? That is not exactly what I am after in a system like this. I want to build a projection of the events. It may be eventually consistent but it must be correct.

And how will it be ensured in my case? I cannot find anything on how the shard is chosen based on the key.

Comment: no. i meam 99% of the scenarios. as i wrote the only case you are in the 1% is when you have small amount of unique entities, and many of them, so your entity will be split over more then 1 shared. if its your case so you are doing something wrong

Comment: To add to this discussion, and maybe help clarify, dynamodb streams are sharded based on partitions, so all actions on items in the same partition will be in the same shard.

Comment: @JonathanSeed Thanks. But the events will by nature be separate items since that is the point of an event store. So an event will be written once an never touched.
Will the solution be to make all events in the same "context" share the same partition to force them on the same shard? But will that have performance issues in DynamoDB since the number of partitions will be bounded by the number of different "contexts"?

Comment: What does "this can happen only if you have small amount of unique entities, any many of them" mean?